# Prevent CherryPy from automatically reloading

Tags: python, cherrypy

It boggles my mind that this hasn't already been asked on Stack Overflow, but I gave it an honest search...

I'm currently developing a simple web application using CherryPy (and routes and Mako, in case its relevant.)  This is going fine except for some *very helpful* mechanism CherryPy possesses that automatically reloads the server process whenever I change the code; inevitably, this will futz with my IDE's debugger, crash due to half-written code, and leave behind a dud process listening on the relevant port that causes later server processes to refuse to run until I manually force-quit it from the task manager.

From looking around, it sounded like this could be disabled via the config dictionary passed to CherryPy as it initializes, e.g.

```
conf = {'/': {'request.dispatch': d, 'engine.autoreload.on' : False}}

cherrypy.tree.mount(root=None, config=conf)
```

This doesn't seem to change anything, however.  Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Are you using quickstart? or engine.start/block?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to configure the the autoreload on the [`global` namespace because is part of the engine](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/config.html?highlight=environment#builtin-namespaces):

```
app_conf = {'/': {'request.dispatch': d}}
cherrypy.config.update({
    'global': {
       'engine.autoreload.on' : False
     }
 })
cherrypy.tree.mount(root=None, config=app_conf)
```

Or better yet set the production environment:

```
 cherrypy.config.update({
     'global': {
        'environment' : 'production'
      }
 })
```

Which will disable the autoreload [among other things](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/src/766259a3f540186e9f5c327d0bb75b7e7fe5d24d/cherrypy/_cpconfig.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#_cpconfig.py-187).

Comment: This is the solution I eventually found, though I used just `cherrypy.config.update({'engine.autoreload.on' : False})`.  Its confusing that cherrypy.config and the "config" parameter to cherrypy.tree.mount are apparently different things.

Comment: cherrypy.config is a dict containing the server settings.

Comment: the config in cherrypy.tree.mount applies to the app you are mounting on that server.